# Cross-site javascript problem

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, xss, cross-site

I'm developing a JavaScript API service. Main html page looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/logic.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1..."></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mydomain/api/main.js"></script>
</head>
...
</html>
```

In the main.js script I load another script from mydomain. I'm doing it by adding script tag ([script.. src="http://mydomain/api/getsomedata.js?callback_id=3434&someparams=..."]). Loaded script imediatly calls API callback function: MyApi.processCallback(...). Everything works ok.

But when I'm trying to load another mydomain script from local file (logic.js), I recive very strange situation: all script global objects are undefined. There is no MyApi object or jQuery $ object which were visible during previous call. So I can't call MyApi callback function.

Perhaps it is because of security restrictions. Anti-XSS, or something similar. I tried to add a X-XSS-Protection header, like in all Google JavaScript APIs. But it did not help.

I don't use IFRAMES.

The problem can be solved exactly, since many cross-site JavaScript API's are working (Google Maps API, etc.) on the same idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening in your script?

If you are doing Ajax calls back to the domain, your script will fail with a Same Origin security error. If you need to do communication with your server from another domain, than you need to use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP) to do it. If you are working with only modern day browser you can get away with [CORS](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/07/cross-site-xmlhttprequest-with-cors/).